# TreeMaker how to write return null statement

Tags: javac, annotation-processor

like this code

```java
public boolean equals(Object o) {
   return null;
}
```

i want use treeMaker write **return null** statement, but i dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake in this question, primitive can not return null.

**return null** statement can gengrated by like this code

```
JCTree.JCStatement aNull = treeMaker.Return(treeMaker.Literal(TypeTag.BOT, null));
```

for example

```java
    public String equal(Object o) {
        return null;
    }
```

```java
    public JCTree.JCMethodDecl generateEqualMethod(JCTree.JCClassDecl classDecl) {
        JCTree.JCModifiers publicModifier = treeMaker.Modifiers(Flags.PUBLIC);
        JCTree.JCExpression returnType = treeMaker.Ident(names.fromString("java"));
        returnType = treeMaker.Select(returnType, names.fromString("lang"));
        returnType = treeMaker.Select(returnType, names.fromString("String"));
        Name method = names.fromString("equal");
        JCTree.JCExpression ObjectExpr = treeMaker.Ident(names.fromString("java"));
        ObjectExpr = treeMaker.Select(ObjectExpr, names.fromString("lang"));
        ObjectExpr = treeMaker.Select(ObjectExpr, names.fromString("Object"));
        JCTree.JCVariableDecl param = 
        treeMaker.VarDef(treeMaker.Modifiers(Flags.PARAMETER),
                names.fromString("o"),
                ObjectExpr,
                null);
        param.pos = classDecl.pos;
        List<JCTree.JCVariableDecl> params = List.of(param);

        List<JCTree.JCStatement> statement = List.nil();
        JCTree.JCStatement aNull = treeMaker.Return(treeMaker.Literal(TypeTag.BOT, null));
        statement = statement.append(aNull);
        JCTree.JCBlock block = treeMaker.Block(0, statement);
        JCTree.JCMethodDecl methodDecl = treeMaker.MethodDef(publicModifier, method, returnType, List.nil(), params, List.nil(), block, null);
        System.out.println(methodDecl);
        return methodDecl;
    }
```